# AWS S3 CLI with Transfer Acceleration Download command throws 400 error : when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to upload/download to S3  with transfer acceleration endpoint in AWS CLI from an EC2.

```
aws s3 cp /home/centos/<FOLDER_NAME> s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<KEY_NAME> --region 
ap-south-1 --endpoint-url http://<S3-Transfer-Acc-endpoint> [--recursive]
```

I am able to upload files and folders successfully and also the download using recursive for folders works.

But when i download a single large file from the bucket, using the following command

```
aws s3 cp s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<KEY_NAME> /home/centos/<KEY_NAME> --region 
ap-south-1 --endpoint-url http://<S3-Transfer-Acc-endpoint>
```

I face the below issue

```
fatal error: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: 
Bad Request
```

Comment: How large is the large file?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot    2.5GB/7GB. I have kept these files in the bucket directly and not inside any folder. I moved these files to a folder and downloaded them recursively. But why do individual files create issue ? and when i run it without transfer acceleration, it works.